# Comparison of abstract algebra structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I made a [comparison table of the different abstract algebra structures](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SLaZHClMQcGd7kuxiNWnFQ2FcwUabnGlheA6q-DDqCE/edit?usp=sharing) to help myself refresh with these concepts.  Can some kind souls here help cross check the basic correctness?  (Any other comments welcomed)

(I've made the file on Google Drive commentable but not directly editable).

Comment: Woah, that is elaborate! Good job.

Comment: Note that the "zero product property for monoid operation" only makes sense if there's also a $0$ floating around, which a general monoid needn't possess. Better to call this the "null factor law" or whatever you called it in high school.

Comment: Also, there's really no point in having a special column for vector space. An $R$-vector space is just an $R$-module such that $R$ is a field. Imo "vector space" is basically leftover terminology from 100 years ago that you're better off avoiding.

Comment: Also, domains are usually assumed commutative AFAIK.

Comment: Also, I would take categories/semicategories/groupoids out of this table altogether. Put them in a different table, with [ringoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ab-enriched+category) and other such multi-object generalizations of familiar structures.

Comment: RE comment#1: Should 'monoid operation' be renamed to 'secondary operation' or something?   When I called it 'monoid operation' I was thinking about then when a ring is formed, a secondary/different operation is required and a monoid is associated with it, in addition to the original group operation associated with an abelian group.

Comment: RE comment#2: but I'm trying to list properties of a general vector space, not just R-vector space.  Also, it's so commonly used still.

Comment: RE comment#3: domains are rings and the first group operation is required to be commutative, but they also have a secondary operation (which I called monoid operation) that are, AFAICT, not required to be commutative.

Comment: Regarding comment 3, yes I just checked up on this and you're right. "Domain" typically means the not-necessarily-commutative version, "integral domain" typically means the commutative version.

Comment: Its probably okay to leave it as "monoid operation", but I would just call it "multiplication". Call it by whatever default symbol you use to denote it. This rarely causes ambiguity or confusion.